# Literature on Accelerated London system

Tags: beginner, london-system, reference-request

I (beginner) have been trying to shift from Philidor Defense (I still play it for Black) to the Accelerated London System for Blitz and Rapid.  For eg:

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nc6 3. e3 Nf6 4. c3 Bf5 5. Bd3 Bxd3 6. Qxd3 e6 7. Nf3 Bd6 8. Bg3 Bxg3 9. hxg3 O-O 10. Ne5 Nxe5 11. dxe5 Ng4 12. Qxh7#
```

Is there any creditable literature or any famous games on:

1. What to do if Black castles Queenside (O-O-O)? The system seems exclusively oriented towards attacking the short castle.
2. Black attempting a similar structure, with the light-square bishop being brought out on move 2? Everywhere I see, this system is only analysed for White to play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [hanging pawns](https://www.youtube.com/c/HangingPawns) YouTube channel has lots of very instructional content on the London system. The videos cover many different responses to the London system and the proper ways to play against them as well as many of the common ideas which you or your opponent will be playing for in each type of position. While the videos are generally best for A players because of their high depth, a beginner would also likely find them very valuable as well, especially if you are interested in learning lots of opening theory.

here is his London theory playlist

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLssNbVBYrGcCjajrI7QtQi48nKOfy-W5O